# How to resolve window.Notification.requestPermission is not a function error?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error "window.Notification.requestPermission is not a function" in chrome.
It is working fine in other browsers.But sometimes I get this error in chrome.

Here is the code -->

```
const checkNotificationPromise = () => {
    try {
      Notification.requestPermission().then();
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  const askNotificationPermission = () => {
    setNotificationPopup(false);
    setWalkthroughText(true);
    function handlePermission(permission) {
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }
      if (Notification.permission === 'denied' || Notification.permission === 'default') {
        setNotificationPopup(false);
        setWalkthroughText(false);
      } else {
        setNotificationPopup(false);
        setWalkthroughText(false);
      }
    }
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {
      console.log('This browser does not support notifications.');
    } else if (checkNotificationPromise()) {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        handlePermission(permission);
      });
    } else {
      Notification.requestPermission((permission) => {
        handlePermission(permission);
      });
    }
  };

return (
   {window?.Notification?.permission === 'default' && (
        <PopupModal
          showModal={notificationPopup}
          headerText={
               <>
                  <p>
                    An event just for you!
                  </p>
              <div className="notification-footer">
                    <Button className="btn btn-link" onClick={closeNotification}>
                      Close
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={askNotificationPermission}>
                      Allow
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  </>
                  }
                 />
                )}

               )
```

What changes do I need to make to get rid of that error?

Comment: Do you have a similar third party API overriding the default implementation as discussed here - https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/227 ?

Comment: No.I don't have similar third party API